# How to exclude uglification for *.min.js in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

As I already have the minified version of `jQuery` and `React`, I do not need the uglification for them. What I want is the `bundle.js` contains the exact same `jquery.min.js` and `react.min.js`. Basically, I would expect `webpack` just will concatenate them. One more thing, I don't want `externals`. How can I achieve it?

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  "entry": ["./src/main/index.js"],
  "output": {
    "filename": "[name].js",
    "libraryTarget": "umd"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        "exclude": /node_modules/,
        "loader": "babel-loader",
        "options": {
          "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "React": "react/dist/react.min.js",
      "ReactDom": "react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      "test": /\.(js)$/,
      "exclude": /node_modules/,
      "compress": true
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try excluding like this `exclude: /\.min\.js$/`

Comment: The implementation of webpack.optimize.uglifyjsplugin does not have exclude. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UglifyJsPlugin` always runs on the entire webpack JS output. There is no way to specify any chunks or modules to ignore o exclude.

If you really don't want Uglify to re-minify those files you have no other option than to use `externals` instead of `alias` and simply concatenate them yourself.

However, I would really, really recommend you to not do things this way. You are generally much better off letting webpack require and minify everything. As long as you set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production` using webpack's `DefinePlugin` the end result will be the same or smaller, and you won't leak React or jQuery to your window.

Comment: Here is what I think. I prefer the official min version over my min version. I am concerned my min version will break the production build. Even I know the official settings/arguments for generating the official min version, these settings/arguments may not fit other libs. And this will cause lots of exceptional cases in the webpack config. I would say nothing is better than official. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Webpack uses Uglify with sensible defaults, you don't have anything to be afraid of. Uglify with default settings is very, very careful, widely used and known not to break anything, so don't worry. I have a ton of websites with webpacked builds in production, totalling over 1 million monthly unique visitors, zero complaints. Everything always just works. Really, don't worry about it!

Comment: Could you show an example of how to exclude in the way you've specified?